# android studio, installation fails while searching for java home

Tags: windows-7-x64, android-studio

My OS Configuration

Windows 7 64 bit.

My android studio installation doesn't go beyond Java Se DEVELOPMENT KIT screen. It crashes and asks to either close or to search online for the solution.

**Note:** This is not the regular problem of it can not be run. And I have my JAVA_HOME variable set. The **problem is in installation, not running...**

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it my self. I am not sure though if this is general or specific to my system.

What I did is.

Select the downloaded android studio installer -> Properties -> Compatibility

1. Check **Run this program in compatibility mode for** and **select windows xp sp2**
2. Check **Run this program as administrator** checkbox

(If it crashes, let it be) and run next time. And for me, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Compatibility mode & run as admin is not needed at all. Which version of JDK did you install?

Comment: it's JDK 7. I had starting installation, but stuck on gradle and have to restart the installation. Installation didn't go beyond JDK search screen. It happened 5 6 time, then I changed compatibility settings and it worked. Though as I have said, it should not be necessarily the case...

Comment: I only have JDK6 for a specific reason and was seeing the $(^NAME) error. Running in compatibility mode worked for me.